# How to fix false action dispatching

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

1. When I click on button app sends request to an API (dispatching signIn action).
2. A server sends error (dispatching signInFailure action).

But in my case dispatching signIn -> signInSuccess -> signInFailure.
Help me please.

**UserService.js**

```
return await axios.post(url, data)
  .then(response => { return response.data; })
  .catch(error => { throw error; });
```

**actions.js**

```
export const signInUser = (username, password) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(signIn({ username, password }));
  userService.signIn(username, password)
    .then(dispatch(signInSuccess()))
    .catch(error => dispatch(signInFailure(error)));
};
```

**Solution**

In *UserService* need to throw an error. And then it works fine in action.

Comment: why are you dispatching  signIn two times in your function. ?

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz signIn - just for fetching flag (payload is useless, my bad)

Comment: signInSuccess - only after success response

Answer (score 0):

Make a change in this function as given below:

```
export const signInUser = (username, password) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(signIn({ username, password }));
  userService.signIn(username, password)
    .then((res) => dispatch(signInSuccess()))
    .catch((error) => dispatch(signInFailure(error)));
};
```

Comment: have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Please use return in catch

```
return await axios.post(url, data)
  .then(response => { return response.data; })
  .catch(error => { return error; }); // Use return here
```

Comment: have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change it

> .then(response => { return response.data; })

to

> .then(response => { if(response.status === 200) return response.data; else throw new Error("error") })

I think it happen when api has response from server ( it isn't going to catch ).